# how to fix ionic application error when we serve the application

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, moodle, ionic4

When we run this command (ionic lab) then it show this error.
how we solve it..

```html
ng run app:serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100
[ng] The run command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Comment: Clearly mentioned that you are not in project directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the command line if you are in the directory containing package.json and run the following commands:

```
 npm install
 ionic serve
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are not inside the right folder. You have to run your `ng run` command in the same place your runned your `ng new` command (or wherever you have initialized your Angular project).

Comment: when we run first time it work and also install some pakage & dependencies.
after Quit when we run again its not work for me.

Comment: Can you post your package.json content please ?